# How to detect arp spoofing using iptable?

Tags: linux, detection, arp-spoofing, iptables

How can I set iptables to detect arp spoofing on linux?

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Are you sure that iptables can do what you expect it to? Do you want to detect or stop ARP spoofing?

Comment: I Just wana to detect

Comment: I have googled but couldn't find any thing usefull. I find only [this](https://kokikode.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/defense-against-arp-spoofing-in-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The iptables command is an interface for the `netfilter` module of linux. Its used to block, redirect,... traffic not to detect MITM attacks. You can detect arp spoofing using a Network Intrusion Detection System (NIDS) like snort for example.

Comment: Are you sure that it's impossible ?